# Accessing Port 8888 in Android Web Browser

Tags: browser, web-server

I'm developing a mobile site which runs on port 8888. I want to see how it looks on my Android phone. How can I use my phone's web browser to view pages on port 8888?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to add the port to the end of the domain as you would with a desktop browser, e.g. `http://mysite.com:8888`. Chrome and the built-in Browser app definitely support this as I use them in this fashion on a daily basis; I'd imagine other browsers would as well since [the syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax) is defined in the RFC specification.

Comment: thanks. I just found out that the problem is on webserver.